# Android how to share URL + text together on social media

Tags: android

I try to share url, pointing to some video in internet, and some text. Url and text need to be shared together, on one click to "share" button. I already know how to share video + text, when video is downloaded to Android device. But I want to share just url to video + text. So, url is actually text by itself, and I can't find way to share 2 separate texts. When I try following:

```
    putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "url")
    putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text2")
```

only text2 is shared.
Here is my code:

```
    val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {

         action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
         type = "*/*"
         putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "url")
         putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text2")

    }

    val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
    startActivity(shareIntent)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why is this happening?*

You are overwriting the text with "text2", this is the reason why only that part is shared, see the corresponding method inside the [Intent](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/135936072b24b090fb63940aea41b408d855a4f3/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#4968) class:

```
public @NonNull Intent putExtra(String name, String value) {
    if (mExtras == null) {
        mExtras = new Bundle();
    }
    mExtras.putString(name, value);
    return this;
}
```

*How to fix this?*

Just combine the URL and the text, e.g.:

```
putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "url" + "\n\n" + "your text");
```

Comment: Thank You a lot, @Droidman ! :) I spent all day struggling with it! Good trick with "\n".